# Qwik not generating a manifest file for SSG site

Tags: static-site-generation, qwik

I am trying to get started with Qwik and SSG.

I have run the following commands in this order

1. npm create qwik@latest

   - selected the basic app
2. npm run qwik add static-node
3. npm run build.static
4. npm run ssg

After doing this I get the following error message:

`Missing client manifest, loading symbols in the client might 404`

Any ideas, I have gone through the SSG documentation but nothing points me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to run `npm run build` to bundle client dist and generate its manifest